# error when switching to different svn branch

Tags: svn, branch, switch-statement

I've got two SVN branches (eg development and stable) and want to switch from one to another...

In every tutorial there is command like:
`rootOfLocalSvnCopy:>svn switch urlToNewBranch .`

But it leads in error in my case:

```
svn: REPORT request failed on '/svn/rootOfLocalSvnCopy/!svn/vcc/default'<br/>
svn: Cannot replace a directory from within
```

Every help that I found is about svn switch --relocate but I don't want to relocate, just to change my working copy to another branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I get it work.

Error was in dot that I used to specify local directory in a command. correct usage is without it, svn can handle it all itself:

*rootOfLocalSvnCopy:>svn switch urlToNewBranch*

(No dot at the end...)