# SVN: switch from nonexistent path?

Tags: svn

I have a repository which was moved, path renamed and then logs truncated. So I don't have old path in it. When I try to do svn switch https://new.repo/new/path svn complains "Cannot replace a directory from within". How do I avoid this?

P.S. Recreating old path is not an option.

Comment: What does it mean to truncate logs?

Comment: Does this solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/115281/395718

Answer (score 2):

If it's still the same repo, and it's just the path to the repo that's changed, then you should be passing the `--relocate` option to `svn switch`.  Does that help?

i.e.

```
svn switch --relocate https://new.repo/new/path
```

(Warning: If it's not the same repo, then using `--relocate` will break things)

Comment: 1. its different repo.
2. relocate says "svn: Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL"

Comment: There is no way to switch to completely different repo. Did you mean it used to be the same repo, but it is changed in new revisions? If so then you should first relocate to //new.repo/old/path and then switch to //new.repo/new/path. If it's completely different repo then you must check it out from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

checkout from new location and copy the contents of old working copy over your new Working copy

Comment: thought about that. thats reserve option i would like to avoid. atm messing with .svn/entries file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. I've created a script that changed path in all .svn/entries. Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, already solved but

```
svn --relocate https://old.repo/old/path https://new.repo/new/path
```

should do the trick nicely

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was not able to get it to work with either "switch" or "switch --relocate". As the original question states, I got the error "Cannot replace a directory from within" with the former and with the latter "Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL"

As I am on CentOS I was able to use sed to manually update the url in the .svn/entries files by running the following from the root of my working directory:

```
find . -type f -name entries -exec sed "s/old\/path/new\/path/" -i {} \;
```